# Appropriate file format for loading list of python objects object-by-object

Tags: python, json, database, serialization, pickle

I have custom python class `Custom` and want to dump/load `List[Custom]` (Let me refer this to a "Chunk" from now).

Also, consider the following setting.

- `Custom` is too complex to hand write serialize/deserialize procedure.
- Although instance of `Custom` is small data size but The chunk tend to be huge like 10GB.

There are so many situation where I need only small portion of the chunk (~10MB). Currently, I use `pickle` as the file format. I load the whole 10GB chunk by `chunk = pickle.load()` and use only small portion of it by like `chunk_use = chunk[:100]`.

However this is memory/computationally inefficient for just use small portion of the chunk. So, it would be nice if I can load the chunk object-by-object like

```py
chunk_use = []
for i in range(100):
    chunk_use.append(load_data(filename, i))
```

or more concisely

```py
chunk_use = load_data(filename, 1, 100)
```

Is there appropriate data format and file format or library to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a database...?

Comment: Not if you serialized it as a `list` object containing other objects. You can, however, loop over the list, `dump` each individual object to a pickle file. Then you can `.load` from that pickle file as many individual objects as you'd like

Comment: Check out rust. Its much faster than Python for this kind of workload.

Comment: I found hdf5 is the one I have been wanted